# Trouble finding var(ax)

Tags: variance, uniform-distribution, dice

So the variance of a 6-sided (1,2,3,4,5,6) die is $291.6$ using the formula:

$$
\text{Var}(X) = \frac{(b-a+1)^2}{12}
$$

Also, $\text{Var}(10X) = 10^2 \cdot \text{Var}(X)$, so that would mean $\text{Var}(10X) = 291.6$.

If I want to find the variance of $10X$, is this not the same as multiplying each of my values by $10$? So that I'm now finding the variance of $(10,20,30,40,50,60)$? If I use the same formula as above, my answer is $216.67$, which is not equal to $291.6$ which I expected. Not exactly sure which part of my logic is incorrect.

Comment: Re "also var(10x) = 10^2var(x), so that would mean var(10x) = 2.916" looks erroneous: when I multiply your initial value of 2.916 by 10^2, I get 291.6, which is what you find later in your post.  What, then, is your question?

Comment: @Richard The formula you propose is suitable as an *estimator* from a *sample.*  It's hard to see how that would apply to characterizing a die, which can be considered a *distribution.*

Comment: yes I edited that error, my question is why using the formula a^var(x) and working out the variance manually using the variance formula is giving me conflicting answers

Comment: I see.  But where does your original formula come from?  I'm sure that if you read the source, it will specify what kind of random variable it applies to and you will discover that the 10,20,...,60 die is not the kind of variable to which it applies.

Comment: the original formula is the variance of a uniform distribution. I'm not entirely sure it wouldn't apply in this case.

Comment: It is a formula *only* for a uniform distribution *on a set of consecutive integers.*

Comment: Ahhhhh okay I understand, thank you very much i've been looking at it and googling things for over an hour

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Let's find a formula that will apply to both your situations.**

One description that covers them both supposes $X$ is a uniform random variable defined on an arithmetic progression

$$x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n = a, a+d, a+2d,\ldots, a+(n-1)d = b.$$

Thus $x_i=a+(i-1)d$ and each $x_i$ has a probability $1/n.$  By definition

$$E[X] = \sum_{i=1}^n \Pr(x_i)x_i = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{n}\, (a+(i-1)d) = \frac{2a+(n-1)d}{2} = \frac{a+b}{2}.$$

Then, also by definition,

> $$\begin{aligned}
> \operatorname{Var}(X) &= E[(X-E[X])^2] = \sum_{i=1}^n \Pr(x_i)(x_i-E[X])^2 \\
> &= \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{n}\, \left(a + (i-1)d - \frac{2a+(n-1)d}{2}\right)^2\\
> &=d^2\frac{n^2-1}{12}.
> \end{aligned}$$

**The factor of $d^2$ is precisely what you expected from the scaling law for the variance.**  Let's check.

1. The standard die is described by $a=1,$ $d=1,$ and $n=6,$ so that $$d^2\frac{n^2-1}{12} = (1)^2 \frac{6^2-1}{12} = \frac{35}{12} = 2.91\bar6.$$
2. Upon multiplying by $10$ we have $a=10,$ $d=10,$ and $n=6$ still, so that $$d^2\frac{n^2-1}{12} = (10)^2 \frac{6^2-1}{12} = 100 \frac{35}{12} = 291.\bar6.$$

When you obtained $216.67,$ you were applying the formula $((b-a+1)^2 - 1)/12$  (notice the additional "-1" in the numerator).  But in terms of $a,$ $n,$ and $d,$ this is

$$\frac{(b-a+1)^2-1}{12} = \frac{(a+(n-1)d - a + 1)^2-1}{12} = \frac{(d(n-1)+1)^2}{12}$$

which gives the correct value only when $d=0$ or $d=1.$ *Your formula does not apply to any other situation.*  That's why we needed to work out the generalization.

Finally, if you would prefer a formula in terms of the two endpoints $a$ and $b$ and the count $n\gt 1,$ you can recover $d$ as

$$d = \frac{b-a}{n-1}$$

and plug that in to get

> $$\operatorname{Var}(X) = \left(\frac{b-a}{n-1}\right)^2 \frac{n^2-1}{12} = \frac{(b-a)^2}{12}\,\frac{n^2-1}{(n-1)^2}.$$

This is informative, because for medium to large $n,$ the second fraction is close to $1$ (the error is on the order of $1/n$) and can be ignored.  What is left is the variance of the variable uniformly distributed over all numbers between $a$ and $b.$  The quadratic dependence on the scale is explicit in the factor $(b-a)^2.$

Comment: Really comprehensive, thank you very much!